# Uploading a default image in html form using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Consider a html form which has different input fields in which one of them is of [type = file] and the user has to upload an image to it, and if the user does not upload an image and clicks submit, I like to update it with a default image of my own and then submit the form.

Does anyone know how to implement it?

Thanks in advance...

My current code looks like this

```js
if(document.getElementById("image") === "") {
    document.image.value="image.jpg";
}
```

```css
form {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  }
input {
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required><br>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" id="mail" required><br>
  <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.png" id="image"><br>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Assuming you are submitting the form to a php page that will then insert the data into a database - I would use a default value in the php page that you submit the form to - ie: rather than uploading a dummy image src in the form inout - have a default img src set when the value of the input is null.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a form `submit` event and check the length of `files` of the `input[type="file"]` inside the event handler function:

```
document.querySelectior("#myform").addEventListener('submit', function() {
    if (document.getElementById("image").files.length == 0) {
        document.img.value="image.jpg";
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share your full code? And what this line means: `document.img.value="image.jpg";`? Where is this `document.img` coming from?

Comment: I think there is nothing called `document.image`. Do you want to update the `src` value of an `image` element? Where do you want to set the default image?

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much for your time. I kinda figured out a different way around.

Answer (score 0):

// HTML

```
<form id="myform">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required><br>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" id="mail" required><br>
      <input type="file" name="image" accept=".jpg,.png" id="image"><br>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
```

// Javascript

```
let defaultFileImage = null;
let url = 'image.jpg';

// convert url image to File object
fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    defaultFileImage = new File([blob], 'image.jpg', blob)
  });

  // submit form
  document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var myform = document.forms.myform;
    var formData = new FormData(myform);
    var userImage = formData.get('image');
    
    if(userImage.name) {      
      console.log(userImage)
    }
    else {
      console.log(defaultFileImage)
    }
  });
```