# HTML form uploading images using JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, image

I have sorted the problem of image thumbnails in my HTML form.

[image]

which was defined the following codes:

```
   <figure>
                                    <!-- Survey images section -->
                                    <h1>Upload survey images</h1>
                                    <div class="surveyimg">
                                        <label for="files">Select survey images: </label>
                                        <input id="surveypics" type="file" multiple/>
                                        <output id="result"/>
                                        <!--<button id="btnUpload">Upload files</button>-->
                                    </div>
                                                            <script>
                                                                //Uploading more than 1 image - imagge thumbnails view
                                                                window.onload = function(){
                                                                    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
                                                                    {
                                                                        var filesInput = document.getElementById("surveypics");
                                                                        
                                                                        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){
                                                                            
                                                                            var files = event.target.files; 
                                                                            var output = document.getElementById("result");
                                                                            
                                                                            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
                                                                            {
                                                                                var file = files[i];
                                                                                
                                                                                if(!file.type.match('image'))
                                                                                continue;
                                                                                
                                                                                var picReader = new FileReader();
                                                                                
                                                                                picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){
                                                                                    
                                                                                    var picFile = event.target;
                                                                                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                                                                                    
                                                                                    div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                                                                                            "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";
                                                                                    
                                                                                    output.insertBefore(div,null);            
                                                                                
                                                                                });
                                                                            picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                                                                            }                               
                                                                        });
                                                                    }
                                                                    else
                                                                    {
                                                                        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                        </script>
                                </figure>
```

and it works fine. However apart from thumbnails they aren't uploaded where I want.

My code for uploading looks like this:

```
   <table id="opresults" class="outputtable"><p class="outputtablehead">Survey Form - output</p>
        <tr class="colname">
            <th class="question">Form question</th>
            <th class="answer">Answer</th>
         </tr>
         <tr class="opcontent">
        <script>
       
            const resultsList = document.getElementById('opresults')
                 const matches = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset");
         
                 const innerBody = document.createElement('tbody')
                 resultsList.append(innerBody);
         
                 new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value, name) => {
                         const row = document.createElement('tr');
                         const tdName = document.createElement('td');
                         const tdValue = document.createElement('td');
         
                         tdName.innerText = name;
                         tdValue.innerText = value;
         
                         row.append(tdName);
                         row.append(tdValue);
         
                         innerBody.append(row);
                 })
         </script>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="img_upload">
    <script>
        const picList = document.getElementById('img_upload')
                    const matches = document.querySelectorAll("output");

                    const innerBody = document.createElement('img')
                    resultsList.append(innerBody);

                    new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((file) => {
                        const row = document.createElement('img');
                    })
        </script>
```

The full form is available here:

https://jsfiddle.net/tjb8163d/1/

and the Javascript code comes from this tutirial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNcJuPIZ2WE&t=371s&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified

which doesn't cover the image submission (they come only as the names instead of files).

I tried to use this option:

https://imagekit.io/blog/client-side-file-upload/

[Uploading a default image in html form using javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64513007/uploading-a-default-image-in-html-form-using-javascript-or-jquery)

but they don't match my situation.

How can I upload images to the server with JavaScript code?

Comment: And server side language is??! Also: https://uploadcare.com/blog/file-upload-ajax/ Short and sweet... It works...

Comment: That would be good, but my whole website is based on the GET method and the form doesn't use PHP.

Comment: That is not what I asked. I think you have trouble understanding basic back -end front -end concept. Your "form" does not have to use PHP. I asked you what server side language do you use?

Comment: In order for you to be able to "upload" image you need to send it from front-ed (using javascript) to back-end. You can do this in two ways in back-ed, upload and save the file on some location on server itself using server side language  or save it in database using base64 encoding/decoding also using server side language. All about upload is server side after you send it with javascript to back-end. And your question has 0 info about server. So nobody can help you.

Comment: It should be still JavaScript frankly. I tried with Node.js but it also wasn't working.

Comment: There is no "It should be still", is it or is is not. If you are sure its node js server then you need to search for "upload file with node js", and if like you said it is not working, then you need to edit question, add this info and that part of code and add problems you are facing, errors and such. If you are planing to get any kind of useful anwser.